# How to get the proper list of SoftLayer datacenters for a given package?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm building an application for ordering hardware and I've seen that I can't get the same list of available datacenters for a given package id. I'm currently using `getRegions()` which it is supposed to return the list of datacenter where the given package is available. However, I have seen that it differs from what I can see in the SoftLayer portal. For instance, for the package 253, I get 28 datacenters. However, if I try to place and order manually from the SL portal, those 28 are not present (just a subset of them).

I imagined that I had to query something else like `isAvailable` or deliveryTimeInformation. `isAvailable` looks to be 1 in all cases and I can't get a value for `deliveryTimeInformation` other than an empty list.

My question is: is there any way to get the same datacenter list you guys show in the SL portal using the API?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I see this is your first post: So just wanted to give you a quick reminder that taglines, and things like "Thanks!" clutter the post and are not needed to answer questions. They're generally discouraged, so in future posts, please try to leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

The method that you’re using is correct, but you have to consider that different packages might have the same product item names, whereas one might be a monthly package and another one an hourly package.

Make sure you're viewing the correct item and package through UI. You could verify this clicking a price in the UI list and checking if it correctly redirects you to a URL that contains a 253 number.

Furthermore, package 253 is allowed in 27 data centers, you can verify using the next request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects.json?objectFilter={"packageId":{"operation":253}}
```

The next request could help you to verify that the processorName “Intel Xeon E5-2650 v3” is contained in more than a single package, one of them is the 253.

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects.json?objectFilter={"processorName":{"operation":"Intel Xeon E5-2650 v3"}}
```

Additionally this link might help you as well:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You